# PHP Index on Function?

Tags: php, function, indexing

I have the following code:

```
$data = unserialize(db::select_xf_session_blob($_COOKIE['xf_session']));
$user_id = $data['user_id'];
```

It seems like a waste to have to declare a variable just so I can take the index of it.

This seems like a more elegant solution:

```
$user_id = unserialize(db::select_xf_session_blob($_COOKIE['xf_session']))['user_id'];
```

But it's not valid, of course.

My question is, is there a more elegant way of writing my first code example?

Comment: It's not valid (yet), but will be with 5.4

Comment: @Jack 5.4 is out and stable, and has been since March...

Comment: @lonesomeday I know, but afaik most distros are still on 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.4 you [can](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101) do the second one. But in the previous versions you have to do the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dummy function:

```
function sub(array $arr, $key) {
    return $arr[$key];
}
```

Like this:

```
$user_id = sub(unserialize(db::select_xf_session_blob($_COOKIE['xf_session'])), 'user_id');
```

Alternatively you could upgrade to the latest version of PHP which supports subscripting expressions.